# Comparison between using DBT + (Athena vs Redshift or Snowflake) as a data warehouse - which path should I take?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena, data-warehouse

I'm currently using DBT and Athena as a data warehouse, and it's able to do transformations and write data back to S3. We don't do any inserts/updates/deletes.

I should say that the amount of data I currently have is quite small, but I imagine Athena can scale well considering it was developed for Facebook.

My question then, is what are the reasons for using Redshift or Snowflake considering how much more expensive they are? What am I missing?

If I had more data, in terabytes perhaps, would this affect the choice of warehouse?

I have not tried Snowflake or Redshift, so perhaps I am missing some context. Happy to learn from you folks!

Answer (score 4):

Reporting systems need a means of **running SQL against data**.

Traditionally, this meant that a Database was required, and all databases (at the time) consisted of both **Storage and Compute**. There was no capability to separate these two components because the database stored its data in a proprietary format and the Compute component was required access that data.

As data volumes increased, traditional databases struggled to provide fast performance. This led to a new class of **Data Warehouse systems** that specialise in querying tables with billions of rows and Terabytes of data. These systems typically use parallel infrastructure and columnar storage split across multiple storage nodes to provide fast performance. Examples are: Amazon Redshift, Snowflake.

The next evolution came from **Presto** (and can be traced back to Hadoop), which was the idea of completely separating the Compute and Storage components of databases. **Optimized for querying**, Presto could query data stored in cloud services (eg Amazon S3) without having to load the data into the database (known as a 'query engine'). This was not only a mind-blowing concept, but depending upon the data format (eg Snappy-compressed Parquet) could actually rival the speed of Data Warehouses. Plus, the fact that they are cloud-native, it was easy to scale Compute as needed for short periods of time.

The main thing to understand about Query Engines is that data is not 'loaded' into them. Rather, when a query runs, they go to the storage service, **look at data stored in whatever format** and then calculate the answer to the query. Data can be added by simply adding another file in the storage location.

Examples of Query Engines are: Presto, Amazon Athena, Amazon Redshift Spectrum

The downside of using Query Engines is that they are not good at inserting/updating data. This has been addressed by the [Delta Lake file format](https://delta.io/) that uses a combination of Parquet files and logs files to allow data to be inserted, updated and deleted. This is the main focus of Databricks.

Of course, if your data needs are small, it is quite acceptable to use a traditional database (eg PostgreSQL) as a Data Warehouse.

The best approach is to **start with something small** until it no longer meets your needs. Then, move to something more powerful. If Amazon Athena is meeting your needs, then there is no need to move to anything else.

(My apologies for not including Google and other services as examples. My knowledge is mostly limited to AWS services.)

Comment: Thanks John, I didn't know a lot of that! I'm keen to understand the pros and cons of using Athena vs Redshift - why would you choose one over the other? I know Athena is meant for analytics traditionally, but these days you can hook it up to DBT and create an ELT workflow that allows you to transform and store data in S3. I'm not very clear on how these two compare against each other.

Comment: Amazon Athena does not support all database operations. For example, you can't use an [UPDATE statement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/update-statement.html) or [DELETE statement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/delete-statement.html) unless using Iceberg tables. It is primarily a query-only engine. Products such as Redshift and Snowflake offer full SQL capabilities. Athena doesn't have a real permissions model -- it relies on S3 permissions to control access to data. There are other limitations like this. However, if Athena works well for you, then keep using it!

Comment: I see! What about when it comes to handling a type 2 SCD? Do you see any major differences in how that would be handled? I think part of my confusion comes from having seen platforms using just S3 and Spark (which I think also don't involve updates/deletes?), with no actual database as part of the system, so perhaps I simply haven't encountered a situation that would require redshift/SF. What situation would require going with redshift/SF? Is it perhaps when the raw data is bad and you have to fix it using updates and deletes?

Comment: I should also say, I'm not at all tied to Athena - I'm trying to learn the differences between these tools and how to pick the right one :)  I appreciate your patience in answering my questions!

Comment: Combining Athena with Lakeformation on glue database and tables gives you really full control on what an AWS principals can access (even in the column level).

Recently dbt-athena-community added support to SCD2 via snapshots, using Iceberg. Also, thanks to Iceberg, Athena really enables you to build a full lakehouse. The only limitation of athena for me are 2: 
- max amount of concurrent queries per account
- low performances on small iceberg tables (consider using parquet in your final presentation layer)
Other than that I can definitely recommend it, as it is really cost-effective.